# json_decode not working on string variable

Tags: php, arrays, json, string, decode

I'm trying to decode a json string into a php array and I'm getting a syntax error (4) when I use json_last_error().

The string comes from an API call to an Infusionsoft database. The database returns an array with one key/value pair. The value contains the json string.

```
Array ( [_PMSChargeItems] => [{"Date":"2012-09-07T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2012-09-07T00:00:00","Amount":41.0},{"Date":"2012-09-07T00:00:00","Amount":64.0},{"Date":"2012-09-11T00:00:00","Amount":80.0},{"Date":"2012-09-11T00:00:00","Amount":474.0},{"Date":"2012-09-19T00:00:00","Amount":82.0},{"Date":"2012-09-19T00:00:00","Amount":125.0},{"Date":"2012-09-19T00:00:00","Amount":127.0},{"Date":"2012-09-19T00:00:00","Amount":174.0},{"Date":"2012-09-19T00:00:00","Amount":343.0},{"Date":"2012-09-19T00:00:00","Amount":618.0},{"Date":"2012-09-19T00:00:00","Amount":1122.0},{"Date":"2012-09-19T00:00:00","Amount":1122.0},{"Date":"2012-09-19T00:00:00","Amount":1122.0},{"Date":"2012-09-27T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2012-10-02T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2012-10-02T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2012-10-10T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2012-11-07T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2012-11-19T00:00:00","Amount":64.0},{"Date":"2012-12-21T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-02-01T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-02-01T00:00:00","Amount":470.0},{"Date":"2013-02-01T00:00:00","Amount":470.0},{"Date":"2013-02-01T00:00:00","Amount":470.0},{"Date":"2013-02-01T00:00:00","Amount":625.0},{"Date":"2013-02-01T00:00:00","Amount":625.0},{"Date":"2013-02-01T00:00:00","Amount":679.0},{"Date":"2013-02-01T00:00:00","Amount":679.0},{"Date":"2013-02-01T00:00:00","Amount":679.0},{"Date":"2013-02-13T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-02-18T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-02-25T00:00:00","Amount":65.0},{"Date":"2013-02-25T00:00:00","Amount":85.0},{"Date":"2013-03-11T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-03-14T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-03-14T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-03-20T00:00:00","Amount":240.0},{"Date":"2013-06-12T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-07-23T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-07-26T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-08-23T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-09-09T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2014-08-04T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2014-08-11T00:00:00","Amount":30.0},{"Date":"2014-08-11T00:00:00","Amount":66.0},{"Date":"2014-08-11T00:00:00","Amount":85.0},{"Date":"2014-09-02T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2014-12-16T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2015-01-09T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2015-02-10T00:00:00","Amount":14.0},{"Date":"2015-02-10T00:00:00","Amount":16.0},{"Date":"2015-02-10T00:00:00","Amount":43.0},{"Date":"2015-02-10T00:00:00","Amount":130.0},{"Date":"2015-02-10T00:00:00","Amount":130.0},{"Date":"2015-02-10T00:00:00","Amount":250.0},{"Date":"2015-02-10T00:00:00","Amount":640.0},{"Date":"2015-02-23T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2015-02-25T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2015-02-25T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2015-03-26T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2015-05-21T00:00:00","Amount":0.0}] )
```

When I save the value to a string variable and pass it to json_decode() I get the syntax error (it doesn't work). If I pass the entire json string itself (copy and paste from echoing the string var value) to json_decode() the array is created (it works).

I have validated the json string at both http://jsonlint.com/ and http://www.functions-online.com/json_decode.html.

How can I get the string to be correctly decoded when it is passed to the json_decode function using a variable?

Here's the code I am using to decode:

```
$cid = $_GET['Id'];
$returnFields = array('_PMSChargeItems');
$conDat = $appConnect->dsLoad("Contact", $cid, $returnFields);

$a = $conDat['_PMSChargeItems'];
var_dump(json_decode($a, true));

echo json_last_error();
```

Here's the result of var_dump($a) before the decode:

```
string(4649) "[{"Date":"2012-09-07T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2012-09-07T00:00:00","Amount":41.0},{"Date":"2012-09-07T00:00:00","Amount":64.0},{"Date":"2012-09-11T00:00:00","Amount":80.0},{"Date":"2012-09-11T00:00:00","Amount":474.0},{"Date":"2012-09-19T00:00:00","Amount":82.0},{"Date":"2012-09-19T00:00:00","Amount":125.0},{"Date":"2012-09-19T00:00:00","Amount":127.0},{"Date":"2012-09-19T00:00:00","Amount":174.0},{"Date":"2012-09-19T00:00:00","Amount":343.0},{"Date":"2012-09-19T00:00:00","Amount":618.0},{"Date":"2012-09-19T00:00:00","Amount":1122.0},{"Date":"2012-09-19T00:00:00","Amount":1122.0},{"Date":"2012-09-19T00:00:00","Amount":1122.0},{"Date":"2012-09-27T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2012-10-02T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2012-10-02T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2012-10-10T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2012-11-07T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2012-11-19T00:00:00","Amount":64.0},{"Date":"2012-12-21T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-02-01T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-02-01T00:00:00","Amount":470.0},{"Date":"2013-02-01T00:00:00","Amount":470.0},{"Date":"2013-02-01T00:00:00","Amount":470.0},{"Date":"2013-02-01T00:00:00","Amount":625.0},{"Date":"2013-02-01T00:00:00","Amount":625.0},{"Date":"2013-02-01T00:00:00","Amount":679.0},{"Date":"2013-02-01T00:00:00","Amount":679.0},{"Date":"2013-02-01T00:00:00","Amount":679.0},{"Date":"2013-02-13T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-02-18T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-02-25T00:00:00","Amount":65.0},{"Date":"2013-02-25T00:00:00","Amount":85.0},{"Date":"2013-03-11T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-03-14T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-03-14T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-03-20T00:00:00","Amount":240.0},{"Date":"2013-06-12T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-07-23T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-07-26T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-08-23T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-09-09T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2014-08-04T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2014-08-11T00:00:00","Amount":30.0},{"Date":"2014-08-11T00:00:00","Amount":66.0},{"Date":"2014-08-11T00:00:00","Amount":85.0},{"Date":"2014-09-02T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2014-12-16T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2015-01-09T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2015-02-10T00:00:00","Amount":14.0},{"Date":"2015-02-10T00:00:00","Amount":16.0},{"Date":"2015-02-10T00:00:00","Amount":43.0},{"Date":"2015-02-10T00:00:00","Amount":130.0},{"Date":"2015-02-10T00:00:00","Amount":130.0},{"Date":"2015-02-10T00:00:00","Amount":250.0},{"Date":"2015-02-10T00:00:00","Amount":640.0},{"Date":"2015-02-23T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2015-02-25T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2015-02-25T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2015-03-26T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2015-05-21T00:00:00","Amount":0.0}]"
```

I've tried to find hidden characters using html_entities and html_entity_decode and didn't find any. I also confirmed using mb_detect_encoding that the string has all ASCII characters.

I just tried the following:

```
var_dump(json_decode(strval($a), true));
```

The result was NULL and the decode error was the syntax error.

What's curious is that var_dump on ($a) gives me a character count of 4649 whereas strlen('[("Date"....) of the string itself gives a character count of 2789...

Comment: Show us the code where you actually call json_decode

Comment: I meant to add that. Thanks! It's there now.

Comment: I'm not familar with this $appConnect->dsLoad(...) function. Can you print_r($a) instead of the decode and tell us what $a contains. Its possible there is an error in $a's content

Comment: The function you're referring to is a function that allows you to access fields in an Infusionsoft database. I just added the result of print_r($a); to the description. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I've done some digging, this is the error you are getting: "JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX  Syntax error"

Comment: Honestly I'm stumped, $a's value is valid json, but it won't decode it. Perhaps try removing the "true" in the json decode. I'm wondering if its trying to index each date/amount pair on some string value, but it needs numbers, though I doubt it.

Comment: can you try print_r(json_decode(strval($a), true));

Comment: Instead of showing print_r, show var_dump($a) as it'll be a little more informative to those that can help.

Comment: Sorry I meant, instead of the decode, as with the first thing I asked, instead of "print_r($a);" use "var_dump($a);"

Comment: Just changed the print_r to var_dump (I changed it on the decode and earlier). Thanks for the suggestion! That's much more helpful to others.

Comment: I just tried this for myself and I could not replicate your error, it works fine for me. Could you show it is encoded? Perhaps there is something happening there. Or something with your PHP version.

Comment: I've never done that before. What would I save to the file? What then would I look for in the 'hex'?

Comment: Try do some random tests, make another simple table with only a couple of rows, and see if you always get this error. May not solve much, but at least narrow the search space a little.

Comment: Great suggestion, I'll do it. Thanks!

Comment: Figured it out. Big thanks to @AndrewB and another guy (Ryan I think) for your helpful comments. I'll post the solution asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all of your help I solved the puzzle!

When the JSON string was returned from the Infusionsoft database all of the quotes were being stored as $quot; instead of as double quotation marks.

I found this out by saving the string to a .txt file (using fopen, fwrite, and fclose) and opening the file with a text editor. I had been figuring that I would need to look at the file with a hex editor (as was recommended by Ryan - I think that's his name anyway, he deleted his comment that contained the suggestion so I'm not sure) but it turns out that wasn't necessary. Here's what the data looked like in the file:

```
[{&quot;Date&quot;:&quot;2012-09-07T00:00:00&quot;,&quot;Amount&quot;:0.0},{&quot;Date&quot;:&quot;2012-09-07T00:00:00&quot;,&quot;Amount&quot;:41.0},{&quot;Date&quot;:&quot;2012-09-07T00:00:00&quot;,&quot;Amount&quot;:64.0},....
```

To remove the quotes I used htmlspecialchars_decode() on the string and then was able to successfully pass the string into json_decode. Here's the code:

```
$a = $conDat['_PMSChargeItems'];
$b = htmlspecialchars_decode($a);
$c = json_decode($b);
```

Thanks again for your helpful comments and answers!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

You are calling json_decode on an array that isn't json encoded, you need to call json_decode on the string that is json_encoded, i.e. the element "_PMSChargeItems" of $a

This seems to work:

```
$a = '[{"Date":"2012-09-07T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2012-09-07T00:00:00","Amount":41.0},{"Date":"2012-09-07T00:00:00","Amount":64.0},{"Date":"2012-09-11T00:00:00","Amount":80.0},{"Date":"2012-09-11T00:00:00","Amount":474.0},{"Date":"2012-09-19T00:00:00","Amount":82.0},{"Date":"2012-09-19T00:00:00","Amount":125.0},{"Date":"2012-09-19T00:00:00","Amount":127.0},{"Date":"2012-09-19T00:00:00","Amount":174.0},{"Date":"2012-09-19T00:00:00","Amount":343.0},{"Date":"2012-09-19T00:00:00","Amount":618.0},{"Date":"2012-09-19T00:00:00","Amount":1122.0},{"Date":"2012-09-19T00:00:00","Amount":1122.0},{"Date":"2012-09-19T00:00:00","Amount":1122.0},{"Date":"2012-09-27T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2012-10-02T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2012-10-02T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2012-10-10T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2012-11-07T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2012-11-19T00:00:00","Amount":64.0},{"Date":"2012-12-21T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-02-01T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-02-01T00:00:00","Amount":470.0},{"Date":"2013-02-01T00:00:00","Amount":470.0},{"Date":"2013-02-01T00:00:00","Amount":470.0},{"Date":"2013-02-01T00:00:00","Amount":625.0},{"Date":"2013-02-01T00:00:00","Amount":625.0},{"Date":"2013-02-01T00:00:00","Amount":679.0},{"Date":"2013-02-01T00:00:00","Amount":679.0},{"Date":"2013-02-01T00:00:00","Amount":679.0},{"Date":"2013-02-13T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-02-18T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-02-25T00:00:00","Amount":65.0},{"Date":"2013-02-25T00:00:00","Amount":85.0},{"Date":"2013-03-11T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-03-14T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-03-14T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-03-20T00:00:00","Amount":240.0},{"Date":"2013-06-12T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-07-23T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-07-26T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-08-23T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-09-09T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2014-08-04T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2014-08-11T00:00:00","Amount":30.0},{"Date":"2014-08-11T00:00:00","Amount":66.0},{"Date":"2014-08-11T00:00:00","Amount":85.0},{"Date":"2014-09-02T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2014-12-16T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2015-01-09T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2015-02-10T00:00:00","Amount":14.0},{"Date":"2015-02-10T00:00:00","Amount":16.0},{"Date":"2015-02-10T00:00:00","Amount":43.0},{"Date":"2015-02-10T00:00:00","Amount":130.0},{"Date":"2015-02-10T00:00:00","Amount":130.0},{"Date":"2015-02-10T00:00:00","Amount":250.0},{"Date":"2015-02-10T00:00:00","Amount":640.0},{"Date":"2015-02-23T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2015-02-25T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2015-02-25T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2015-03-26T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2015-05-21T00:00:00","Amount":0.0}]';
print_r( json_decode( $a ) );
```

or the array way:

```
$a = array( '_PMSChargeItems' => '[{"Date":"2012-09-07T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2012-09-07T00:00:00","Amount":41.0},{"Date":"2012-09-07T00:00:00","Amount":64.0},{"Date":"2012-09-11T00:00:00","Amount":80.0},{"Date":"2012-09-11T00:00:00","Amount":474.0},{"Date":"2012-09-19T00:00:00","Amount":82.0},{"Date":"2012-09-19T00:00:00","Amount":125.0},{"Date":"2012-09-19T00:00:00","Amount":127.0},{"Date":"2012-09-19T00:00:00","Amount":174.0},{"Date":"2012-09-19T00:00:00","Amount":343.0},{"Date":"2012-09-19T00:00:00","Amount":618.0},{"Date":"2012-09-19T00:00:00","Amount":1122.0},{"Date":"2012-09-19T00:00:00","Amount":1122.0},{"Date":"2012-09-19T00:00:00","Amount":1122.0},{"Date":"2012-09-27T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2012-10-02T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2012-10-02T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2012-10-10T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2012-11-07T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2012-11-19T00:00:00","Amount":64.0},{"Date":"2012-12-21T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-02-01T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-02-01T00:00:00","Amount":470.0},{"Date":"2013-02-01T00:00:00","Amount":470.0},{"Date":"2013-02-01T00:00:00","Amount":470.0},{"Date":"2013-02-01T00:00:00","Amount":625.0},{"Date":"2013-02-01T00:00:00","Amount":625.0},{"Date":"2013-02-01T00:00:00","Amount":679.0},{"Date":"2013-02-01T00:00:00","Amount":679.0},{"Date":"2013-02-01T00:00:00","Amount":679.0},{"Date":"2013-02-13T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-02-18T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-02-25T00:00:00","Amount":65.0},{"Date":"2013-02-25T00:00:00","Amount":85.0},{"Date":"2013-03-11T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-03-14T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-03-14T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-03-20T00:00:00","Amount":240.0},{"Date":"2013-06-12T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-07-23T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-07-26T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-08-23T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2013-09-09T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2014-08-04T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2014-08-11T00:00:00","Amount":30.0},{"Date":"2014-08-11T00:00:00","Amount":66.0},{"Date":"2014-08-11T00:00:00","Amount":85.0},{"Date":"2014-09-02T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2014-12-16T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2015-01-09T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2015-02-10T00:00:00","Amount":14.0},{"Date":"2015-02-10T00:00:00","Amount":16.0},{"Date":"2015-02-10T00:00:00","Amount":43.0},{"Date":"2015-02-10T00:00:00","Amount":130.0},{"Date":"2015-02-10T00:00:00","Amount":130.0},{"Date":"2015-02-10T00:00:00","Amount":250.0},{"Date":"2015-02-10T00:00:00","Amount":640.0},{"Date":"2015-02-23T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2015-02-25T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2015-02-25T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2015-03-26T00:00:00","Amount":0.0},{"Date":"2015-05-21T00:00:00","Amount":0.0}]' );
print_r( json_decode( $a['_PMSChargeItems'] ) );
```

You seem to mix up JavaScript and PHP

Comment: I don't think I gave you enough information (my apologies if that's the case). I just added the code that I used for the json_decode to the description. I stored the array value in a variable and passed that variable to json_decode().